# Insert string before first occurance of a character

Tags: javascript

I have a function to import image files and I want to associate the thumbnail with the original files. I need to insert `_og` before the first occurrence of a period. Can someone help me with the regex or know of a different way?

```
importAll(r) {
    let imageArray = r.keys();

    // This removes the actual original file from the array 
    // so it only includes the thumbnails since they are all in the same directory.
    imageArray = imageArray.filter(s => !s.includes('_og'));

    imageArray.forEach(key => (
        this.images.push({
            path: r(key), // thumbnail
            pathOriginal: r(key).replace(/./g , "_og."), // original
        })
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is a special character in regex that means to match any character, so you should escape it:

```js
.replace(/\./g, "_og.")
```

On a side note, I'm pretty sure you're looking for `Object.keys(r)` instead of `r.keys()`, and `r[key]` instead of `r(key)`.

Comment: Okay the escape works but I have multiple `.` in the string and I only want to replace the first occurrence, thanks.

Comment: @Josh, just remove `g` key to replace the 1st match only